# What's the cleanest way to achieve this behavior using Angular Router?

Tags: angular, architecture, angular-router

Currently I have this simple app that has a sidebav in the left with a list of items and when you select one of them, in the right there will be 3 tabs that will show different info about the selected item. let's say: Information, Reviews, Images.

Currently, the ID of the selected item isn't used in the URL, so basically the URL will always be like this:

```
.../item/information
.../item/reviews
.../item/images
```

When I select an item in the sidenav, I next() into a BehaviorSubject the selected ID and in each of these 3 components I listen to the BS.asObservable() and switchMap to the GET endpoint for each product section (getInfo, getReiews, getImages - these aren't the actual enpoint names, just an example).

The problem is, now I want to have in the URL of the selected product ID as well. So my new URLs would be like:

```
.../item/123/information
.../item/123/reviews
.../item/123/images
```

My question is, what's the best practice/cleanest solution to achieve this?

I was thinking I can update my routing to be something like this

```
{
  path: ':id/information',
  component: ItemInfo
},
{
  path: ':id/reviews',
  component: ItemReviews
},
{
  path: ':id/images',
  component: ItemImages
},
```

And from the sidenav, now instead of next-ing into the BS, I just navigate to the route ['item', item.id, 'information'], etc.

And in each component Info, Reviews, Images I subscribe to activatedRoute.params and switchMap the itemId to the API get.

The problem is, **I'm not sure this is the cleanest way to do this**. What if I will have 10 tabs in the future? Specs, Videos, etc.. I add this subscribe and switchMap logic in all of them?

I was thinking maybe I can have a wrapper component where I read the id from the URL, then in that component separate children for each tab, but how can I pass the ID to each component and still have separate URLs for each component? I would still need routing and then pass the info as router data? not a big improvement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to take a look at a store concept- namely ngrx. You could get the data once and then just select it from the store. Ngrx also provides a routing integration, so you could easily combine that. https://ngrx.io/

Comment: Thanks. NgRx is out of the question for this project. And I'm only interested in the router structure, not sure how NgRx would fit into that.

Comment: How come? Your BehaviorSubject solution actually gets pretty close to NGRX already. Routing is integrated via a router store in NGRX and is pretty easy to use imo once you have it all set up. I think your routing definition is actually fine, your question was rather about "The problem is, I'm not sure this is the cleanest way to do this. What if I will have 10 tabs in the future? Specs, Videos, etc.. I add this subscribe and switchMap logic in all of them?" - NGRX would take care of that. At the end of the day, you have to get & manage the data somehow ;)

Comment: @Loop if someone says they don't want to use a 3rd party lib it's best not to push it on them. ngrx is great but OP knows their requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can to have in "home" the "sidenav" and the "tabs".

To automatic, we are going to define a routes like

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'item/:id/information',
    component: ComponentOne,
    data:{label:'Information',path:'/information'}
  },
  {
    path: 'item/:id/reviews',
    component: ComponentTwo,
    data:{label:'Reviews',path:'/reviews'}
  },
  {
    path: 'item/:id/images',
    component: ComponentThree,
    data:{label:'Images',path:'/images'}
  },
];
```

Some like (sorry about the ugly routerLink, I can not make work with relative paths)

```
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
      <a
        routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLink]="['/item/'+item.id+'/information']"
      >
        {{item.text}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
<nav *ngIf="router.url!='/'">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let route of routes">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        [routerLink]="router.url.split('/').slice(0,3).join('/')+route.path"
        routerLinkActive="active"
      >
        {{route.label}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<article><router-outlet></router-outlet></article>
```

Don't forget inject as public the router

```
constructor(public router:Router){}
```

See that, using "appRoutes", the only you need is change the "appRoutes" array to take more "tabs"

Each component in the way

```
  sub:Subscription;
  constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub=this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.name = params['id'];
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.sub.unsubscribe()
  }
```

See that it's the component who ask about the parameter. You needn't use "subject"

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrzdgs?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: hm.. I don't get it, how is this different then my approach? this is basically what I said I'm doing but I'm not 100% happy with this, mostly because I have to read the ID param in each tab

Comment: @LarryP, sorry, I understand you want not use a Subject else get the "id" subscribing to activateRouter.params. If your router include the "id" as params, I feel it's more "natural" get the id from the param (makes less dependent the components), but it's only one personal opinion.

Comment: @LarryP, you can store in a service the result of "getInfo()", "getReiews()", "getImages()". This it's make by the "sidenav" before navigate. Then each component ask about "this.dataService.info", "this.dataService.reviews", "this.dataService.images". In this way you have "all in one component" and you can not subscribe in each component

Answer (score 0):

If we can to have "all in one place", we can, e.g. use a service where store the information

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class DataService {
 information:any;
 reviews:any;
 images:any
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  getInformation(id:number)
  {
    return httpClient.get(...).pipe(
       tap(res=>this.information=res)
    )
  }
  getReviews(id:number)
  {
    return httpClient.get(...).pipe(
       tap(res=>this.reviews=res)
    )
  }

  getImages(id:number)
  {
    return httpClient.get(...).pipe(
       tap(res=>this.images=res)
    )
  }
```

Then our sideNav has a function

```
  navigateTo(id:number){
     forkJoin([
               this.dataService.getImages(id),
               this.dataService.getInformation(id),
               this.dataService.getReviews(id)
     ]).subscribe(_=>{
       this.router.navigate(['/item/'+id+'/information'])
     });
  }
```

Now, the only in ours component we inject the service

```
  constructor(public dataService:DataService) {}

  <pre>{{dataService.information|json}}</pre>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zf1634?file=src%2Fdata.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fone.component.ts,src%2Fthree.component.ts,src%2Ftwo.component.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css)